# Ajax Jquery form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello I am running a form using ajax submit functions using PHP and JS
bellow is my code

**submit.php**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['add_data'])){
    echo "add id";
}
if(isset($_POST['update_data'])){
    echo "update_id";
}
?>
```

***Form.js***

```
$('form.data').on('submit',function(){
    var info = $(this),
        url = info.attr('action'),
        method = info.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    info.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        var info= $(this),
            name = info.attr('name'),
            value = info.val();
        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: method,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            //refresh total
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

***form.php***

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php" class="data">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<button name="add_data" class="btn btn-label-success btn-sm mg-y-5"><i class="fa fa-link"></i>
<button name="update_data" value="update" class="btn btn-label-warning btn-sm mg-y-5"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> Update</button>
</form>
```

however the result I am getting is not correct if I click one of the button the console replies:
`add idupdate_id`

instead of one of the following
`add id`
or
`update_id`

Comment: Check result of `console.log(data)` before `ajax`. Is it correct? Then check `print_r($_POST);` in php.

Comment: the result is like this ``` add_data: "" update_data: "" id:""``` @AksenP

Comment: So, this is the answer. You're passing this variables and they're `isseted`.

Comment: yes but how can I separate them? like if i click the update button this will execute the update and if the add button this will execute the add function

Comment: Why not simply: `data : {function: 'add'},` On php : `if(isset($_POST['function'])){ if($_POST['function'] == "add"){ echo "add id"; } }`

Comment: You need to change the submit way, which will be settled on the button and this button will submit the form you desired.

Comment: @LADevelopers, look at answers below

Answer (score 0):

On submit you are going to have the value set so `isset` will always return true. What you must do is:

```
if(!empty($_POST['add_data'])){
    echo "add id";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your form contains both add_data and update_data, so they will be always set in `$_POST`. If you want different action for each button, you could assign a function to the `onClick` event to both buttons, check which caused the event and pass it to your AJAX data.

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php" class="data">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<button name="add_data" class="btn btn-label-success btn-sm mg-y-5"><i class="fa fa-link"></i>
<button" name="update_data" value="update" class="btn btn-label-warning btn-sm mg-y-5"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> Update</button>
</form>
```

Then in your JS:

```
$("button").click(function(){
 var info = $(this),
    url = info.attr('action'),
    method = info.attr('method'),
    data = {};

info.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
    var info= $(this),
        name = info.attr('name'),
        value = info.val();
    data[name] = value;
});
data["action"] = ($(this).attr("name") === "add_data") ? 0 : 1; //If add_data -> 0 else -> 1

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: method,
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        //refresh total
    }
});
return false;
});
```

And then in your PHP, you look for `$_POST["action"]` variable

```
if($_POST["action"] == 0) {
echo "add_data";
} else {
echo "update_data";
}
```

**EDIT:** If you would like to, you don't have to check it in a condition, and just past the name attribute to `data["action"]` and then check in PHP, if `$_POST["action"]` is equal to add_data or update_data

Comment: It's useless info for `post` request via giving names to each button during form submission.

Comment: @AksenP Yes, I know, but it was a part of the original code, so I wanted to preserve it the way asker had it. But I understand that I should have pointed that out. Thank you

Comment: Just come back if something is not clear to you or if you need some additional assistance with this. And make sure you mark the correct answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score -1):

Use next code for separating your button actions:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php" class="data">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<button value="add" class="btn btn-label-success btn-sm mg-y-5"><i class="fa fa-link"></i>Add</button>
<button value="update" class="btn btn-label-warning btn-sm mg-y-5"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> Update</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('form.data > button').on('click',function(){
    var info = $(this).parent(),
        url = info.attr('action'),
        method = info.attr('method'),
        task = $(this).val(),
        data = {};

    info.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        var info= $(this),
            name = info.attr('name'),
            value = info.val();
        data[name] = value;
    });
    data['task'] = task;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: method,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            //refresh total
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'add'){
    echo "add id";
}
if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'update'){
    echo "update_id";
}
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of what you changed and _why_.

Comment: @04FS, I didn't change it, I've add `name`s of `input`s, for example his `input name="id"`. Btw you can see editation history.

Comment: I am not talking about the edit history of your answer. _“Use next code for separating your button actions:”_ - you should _explain why_, not _just_ show code.

Comment: @04FS, this code is easy to read or I should post many tutorial links on what I did?

Comment: You should explain why / how this solves the problem OP was having. They obviously did not understand what they were doing enough to be able to solve the problem by themself, so “easy to read” should not be the sole criterion here. Ideally they (or anyone else finding it later) would _learn_ something from your answer, but as it is right now, it will probably just serve as a “copy&paste-solution”. I am not saying write a full-on tutorial, but something like “what you had was not working because […], I fixed this by doing […] instead.”

Comment: @04FS, 90% answers here presented in the same way. First of all look at the comments here and you'll get that this is **another submit way** about which I told in comments.